# How to host a CNN Neural Network on a fast webserver?

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, webserver, gunicorn

I'm looking to host a keras tensorflow python neural network on a webserver/tcp/rpc/whatever,
basically people would be able to make requests to an API that's written in python, and they would get a result generated by the neural network.

My original approach is to write a webserver in Flask and use gunicorn to multi-thread it for performance, however this approach can't handle more than 500 requests/second.. (I'm aiming for 5000requests/second+)

What is the best way of doing this? I've heard of FastAPI but I haven't seen a lot of papers about it and I don't want to rework my whole webserver only to find out that it didn't increase the performance at all...

Comment: Have you made sure your model is global, and not re-created for every request?

Comment: Yes.. The model load function is only called once